# Ansible - dynamic variable content

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I've got an environment with 3 boxes and part of the installation job creates a backup script and an associated cron job to the run the script. Currently, the job just goes onto the 01 instance and runs every hour.

```
- name: Create Backup script cron job
  cron:
    name: "S3 Backup"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "{{ backup_frequency }}"
    job: "{{ app_home_dir }}/tools/aws_s3_backup.sh"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['admin']
  become: true
```

I'd like to have it so that the script goes onto all 3 instances and the cronjob is created on all three, but with the respective boxes only running every 3rd hour...

```
Box 1 ... hour : 01,04,07,10,13,16,19,22
Box 2 ... hour : 02,05,08,11,14,17,20,23
Box 3 ... hour : 03,06,09,12,15,18,21,00
```

I know the maths theory for getting the relevant hours - i.e. get the box number and then loop through 0-23 doing modulo 3 on counter and seeing if it equals {box num}, and if so include it in the hours list for that box.

However, what I don't know, is whether this needs to be done via Jinja or can be done in the Ansible code itself directly? And then how?

Any help would be much appreciated please!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your hostnames are something like `box-1`, `box-2`, etc, you could do something like this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        backup_frequency: >-
          {{ range(box_num|int, 25, 3)|join(", ") }}
      vars:
        box_num: >-
          {{ inventory_hostname.split('-')[1]|int }}

    - debug:
        var: backup_frequency
```

This *almost* works and produces values for `backup_frequency` that look like:

```
ok: [box-1] => {
    "backup_frequency": "1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22"
}
ok: [box-2] => {
    "backup_frequency": "2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23"
}
ok: [box-3] => {
    "backup_frequency": "3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24"
}
```

Note that erroneous `24` for `box-3` at the end. We could fix that if Ansible had a `modulo` function...it doesn't, but we can provide one by dropping the following code into `filter_plugins/filters.py`:

```py
def filter_modulo(v, mod):
    return v % mod

class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
                'modulo': filter_modulo,
                }
```

That allows us to write:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        backup_frequency: >-
          {{ range(box_num|int, 25, 3)|map('modulo', 24)|join(", ") }}
      vars:
        box_num: >-
          {{ inventory_hostname.split('-')[1]|int }}

    - debug:
        var: backup_frequency
```

Which produces:

```
ok: [box-1] => {
    "backup_frequency": "1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22"
}
ok: [box-2] => {
    "backup_frequency": "2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23"
}
ok: [box-3] => {
    "backup_frequency": "3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 0"
}
```

...which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

- Set the frequency, get the ranges of hours and shuffle the list (depending on where you want to start)

```yaml
  freq: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|length }}"
  ranges: |
    [{% for start in range(freq|int) %}
    {{ range(start, 24, freq|int) }},
    {% endfor %}]
  ranges0: "{{ ranges[1:] + [ranges.0] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ranges0:
    - [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22]
    - [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23]
    - [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

- Get the index and set the hours

```yaml
  index: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "hour: {{ ranges0[index|int]|join(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [box-1] => 
  msg: 'hour: 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22'
ok: [box-2] => 
  msg: 'hour: 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23'
ok: [box-3] => 
  msg: 'hour: 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21'
```

- Optionally, use the range format

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "hour: {{ r[0] }}-{{ r[-1] }}/{{ freq }}"
      vars:
        r: "{{ ranges0[index|int] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [box-1] => 
  msg: 'hour: 1-22/3'
ok: [box-2] => 
  msg: 'hour: 2-23/3'
ok: [box-3] => 
  msg: 'hour: 0-21/3'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: box-1,box-2,box-3

  vars:

    freq: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|length }}"
    ranges: |
      [{% for start in range(freq|int) %}
      {{ range(start, 24, freq|int) }},
      {% endfor %}]
    ranges0: "{{ ranges[1:] + [ranges.0] }}"
    index: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ranges0|to_yaml
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "hour: {{ ranges0[index|int]|join(',') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "hour: {{ r[0] }}-{{ r[-1] }}/{{ freq }}"
      vars:
        r: "{{ ranges0[index|int] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in happening inside the curly braces, with jinja syntax.

pseudo looking like

`hour: {{ box_name | regex'[0-9]'| to_int | modulo(3) }}`